# MAX value using lookup for comma-separated list in one of the columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This formula is SO close to what I am looking for.

```
Keys            Scores          
k1  10          k1,k2
k2  15          k3
k3  8           k1,k2,k3


=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(E2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))))
```

It works great but instead of it providing a SUM of the Scores I like it to provide the max value of the Scores based on the comma separated string entered.

Can it be done?

Tried substituting MAX and MAXA for SUMPRODUCT

[image: Example of current functionality.]

In this example my dep_val indicates the End Date that I want to reference to populate the Start Date while allowing only workdays and no holidays and it works well.

What I would like to do is enter a string such as 3,4,5 as the dep_val for Task 6 and have the formula return the MAX value End Date in Tasks 3,4,& 5.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: can you provide the desired results for the data sample? So we know what to aim for. Please edit your question to do that. Then post a comment

Comment: First time see someone using **SUMIF** in a way as **INDEX+MATCH**, interesting :)

Comment: Hello, I've updated my question and hopefully this will clear up what I am looking for. Also, Someone mentioned entering an Array with Ctrl-Shift-Enter which I have tried and it doesn't paste anything. Then I read online that Excel 2016/O365 doesn't require Arrays to be entered that way any longer. Which is correct? Thanks to all!

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions for solving the functionality described above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MAX() instead of SUMPRODUCT() but then you need to enter the formula as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Formula solution for Excel 2013 or above in the use of FILTERXML function

Formula in F2, copied down :

```
=AGGREGATE(14,,LOOKUP(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(E2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),A$2:B$4),1)
```

Edit: The above formula Lookup list must be sorted in ascending order because the using of LOOKUP function and it is a normal formula.

Or,

You can use the VLOOKUP function without sorting instead, and it is an array formula must confirmed with SHIFT+CTRL+ENTER entry

```
=MAX(VLOOKUP(T(IF({1},FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(E2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"))),A$2:B$4,2,0))
```

Comment: A good answer but you should mention the `Keys` column must be in ascending order.

Comment: @ Terry W, thanks for the advice. It is true that the Lookup list must be sorted in ascending order because the using of LOOKUP function, I shall edit the post.

Comment: no worries but I believe you can come up another solution without using LOOKUP :)